Connection to router's default gateway timing out
I want to access my router's configuration page in order to open some ports I need. After finding its default gateway adress, which is 192.168.1.1, I tried to access it through my browser. After a little while, it says that the connection has timed out. I then tried to ping 192.168.1.1, but the command returns nothing except:PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.. Keep in mind that it is works otherwise normally and is able to access the internet. The model of the router is Huawei DG8245V. Any ideas?
Thanks!

Where did you obtain this address from?

What is the IP address of your PC on which is being used to attempt access to the router's configuration page? Also, according to DG8245V model on the Huawei forum the default IP address should be printed on the nameplate of the router. Have you checked the information on the nameplate?

I got the default gateway address from the sticker on the router and I confirmed it with the command ip route | grep default. The IP of my PC is 192.168.1.101.

Did you try rebooting the router? Maybe its HTTP server process crashed or something else went haywire in its network stack.

I did, but it didn't help.
